# Convert a retail Sims 3 save file into a Steam Sims 3 save file

Tags: steam, the-sims-3

I have a copy of *The Sims 3* that I bought from a retail store.

Having got sick of dragging out a CD drive to play the game, I re-bought the game in digital download form when it was on super-sale on Steam.

Is it possible to transfer my existing save into the new install somehow?

Comment: Just so you know, if you install Origin, you can use your Sims CD key to unlock a downloadable version which doesn't need the CD in drive, and it still uses the old save's location

Comment: Maybe the save location is differnt? Have you tried moving it?

Answer (score 4):

The save games should carry over between installations. I recently purchased Sims 3 on Steam and my save games and custom content from my previous retail installation worked fine.

When you uninstall(ed) Sims 3 retail, you are prompted with a dialog if you want to keep saved games, custom content, etc.. You will have to make sure you tell it to keep your content.